# How to add a project to an internally hosted Nuget

Tags: nuget

Where I work we have a good number of shared projects and we are thinking of using an internal Nuget repository to manage them.

Type of projects involved

- Shared Objects (A collection of classes that will be used by different applications
- Database projects using Entity Framework
- WCF

What they all have in common is that they can be compiled into a dll.  And this is what we were planning to do.

1. Compile a dll
2. Create Nuget package for the dll
3. Use Nuget to add the project into our applications

The question is.  Are there any disadvantages to using a dll over the source code itself?

Answer (score 1):

One disadvantage might be that you cannot debug if you just have the DLLs in your Nuget packages. But there is a solution to this. You can pack the PDB files as well so you can [debug a referenced dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130417/how-to-debug-a-referenced-dll).
In addition, there is a certain amount of work for creating and managing your packages. Only you and your colleges can decide if the advantages are worth this investment.
You might find some more hints in [advantages of using a private nuget server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689198/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-a-private-nuget-server).